# howto get arguments parsed into send email in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

since mailutils is not available I am trying to write a simple python script that sends email like:

```
echo text | mail -s "some subject" -r jo@do.com
```

I have succeeded catching arguments and printing them, but I do not know howto get these arguments into an email header part.

The script runs like this

```
./m2.py -s "dag mijnheer" -r hanscees@hanscees.con
```

The script runs, but this fails very much.. In the script below the email headers are empty, although it arrives as an email.

I also tried using smtpObj.sendmail(sender, RECIPIENT, message2)

But that doesn't work. 
How do I get these headers filled with text and variables?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import smtplib

## get commandline arguments
def commandLineSetup():
    commandParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Sends email "
                                                         "to email server by smtp")
    commandParser.add_argument("-s", "--subject", help="Subject of email")
    commandParser.add_argument("-r", "--recipient", help="emailaddress of recipient")

    args = commandParser.parse_args()

    return args.subject, args.recipient

def main():
    SUBJECT, RECIPIENT = commandLineSetup()

    # Check that proper inputs were provided
    if not SUBJECT or not RECIPIENT:
        print ("Insufficient inputs provided")
        exit()
    sender = "docker79@hanscees.con"
    print ("sendto adress is", RECIPIENT)
    #built list with text message
    message2 = 'FROM: '+sender+'\n'+'TO: '+RECIPIENT+'\n'+'SUBJECT: ',SUBJECT,'\n'
    print ("messages2 is", message2)

    message = """From: sender
    To: RECIPIENT
    Subject: SUBJECT

    This is a test e-mail message.
    """
    try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('192.168.0.111')
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, RECIPIENT, message)
       print ("Successfully-sent-email")
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
       print ("Error-unable-to-send-email")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, found an answer combining several places.
Here is a python3 script for sending email that actually works fine.
Didn't find this anywhere on the internet to my amazement.
Any improvements are welcome. Because it will probably crash your computer if you cat /dev/null into it :(

use it like this

```
echo some text | pymail3.py -s "how are you " -r somebody@somewhere.com
```

Be advised you must manually add your mailserver and from address in the script. It will send email to port 25 only.

#### pymail3.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.utils import make_msgid

## get commandline arguments
def commandLineSetup():
    commandParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Sends email piped in "
                                                         "to email server by smtp")
    commandParser.add_argument("-s", "--subject", help="Subject of email")
    commandParser.add_argument("-r", "--recipient", help="emailaddress of recipient")
    args = commandParser.parse_args()
    return args.subject, args.recipient

def main():
    SUBJECT, RECIPIENT = commandLineSetup()

    # Check that proper inputs were provided
    if not SUBJECT or not RECIPIENT:
        print ("Insufficient inputs provided")
        exit()
    sender="dockerdaemon79@hanscees.con"
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] =  SUBJECT
    msg["From"] = Address("dockershost", addr_spec=sender)
    msg["To"] =  Address("whomwever", addr_spec=RECIPIENT)
    
    #lets get text from stdin
    data = ""
    for line in sys.stdin:
       data += line
    msg.set_content (data)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('192.168.0.254', 25)

    try:
       server.send_message(msg)
       server.quit()
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
       print ("Error-unable-to-send-email")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```